# How to use increment method for findElement code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm stuck with how to implicate increment into find element code

this is the code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@class='_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b'])[13]")).click();
```

I need to change 13 into 13 + 1 and 14 + 1 and so on every time loop happens.

Comment: it's not clear what you want, can you explain in a more detailed manner?

Comment: How about using findElements and iterating the list...

Comment: this has nothing to do with the selenium or webdriver, this is basic programming 101. without learning that don't jump on using selenium. you will get those issues on every step.

Comment: @GaurangShah hi there any sugestion on what book should i read first actually i learn a few basic on the internet but not all of the basic learned

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-books-to-learn-Java

Answer (score 1):

Use variable

```
for (int i = 13 ; i < limit ; ++i) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@class='_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b'])[" + i + "]")).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this:

```
int ord = 13;
String xpath = "(//a[@class='_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b'])[%s]";
// some sort of loop starts, e.g. while, for, etc
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(xpath, ord))).click();
    ord++;
// the loop ends
```

Explanation: `String.format()` lets you use `printf` -like string templates. In your case the variable part of the template is the ordinal number, `ord`. You can increment it with `ord++` whenever it seems necessary.